# how to print a part of a statement in file handling in python?

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I am having a problem.
I am trying to figure out how to print a part of a statement in file handling.

For example,
you have a sentence that you want to print. but, you do not want to print the whole thing.

Comment: What is the relevance of file handling to the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Add what code you've tried with examples of input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, you are trying to print out one string out of an entire file. To print out one line, you could use:

```
f = open("file.in", "r") # opens a file named "file.in" for reading
line1 = f.readline()
```

This reads in one line of the file. To print it out, simply write:

```
print(line1)
```

You have only read one line of the file and did not print out the entire file. Hope this helps!